# Using json in android

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I'm developing an android application with the detailed approaches of a Project with sales and purchasing management.

For that i'm using Login and other screen applications..

My project have run correctly in `SQLite` Database, how can i make it as Centralized using the `JSON`?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html

Comment: Try some google , you get idea

Comment: I will look out the Tutorial, Nirav Ranpara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Json with the PHP and MYSQL for the centralised application..

See the following tutorial for the Login activities,..

[login](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wW3nQzw6PnY)

And other database activities like, Creating, inserting, fetching, updating and deleting the data on the server side database, follow this tutorial,..

[PHP & MYSQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Here the Important thing is, you need to create a Server side database for yours application..

And the following java file is more important for the JSON activities,..

```
JSONParser.java
 package com.example.androidhive;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
 import java.util.List;
 import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
 import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
 import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;
 import android.util.Log;
 public class JSONParser {
 static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";
 // constructor
public JSONParser() {
 }
 // function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {
     // Making HTTP request
    try {
         // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
             HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
         }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
             HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           
     } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
     // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
     // return JSON String
    return jObj;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Refer above link for Jsonparsing tutorials. Basically you will require JSONParser.java from the example which return json object from url.

link also includes downloadable code. But make sure you use AsyncTask to perform all your network based tasks.